# TortoiseHg push to BitBucket fails wirh Invalid Argument error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

We are using TortoiseHg with BitBucket. There are two developers working remotely on the project. Everything was running smooth for past 2 months until yesterday. Since I pulled latest updates and added my changes I cannot push to BitBucket anymore. When I use Workbench to push it gives me the following error:

abort: push creates new remote head xxxxx
hint: did you forget to merge? use push -f to force

I didnt forget to merge, all my changes are commited and merged with changes from other developer.

I tried doing forced push "hg push -f --traceback" but that fails as well with:

abort: Invalid Argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
 Fails on
  File "mercurial\revlog.pyo" in **init**

Comment: Forgot to mention we are using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010 for development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing a hg pull first?  There may be some recent changes that you don't have in your local repository, that you need to merge in before you can push.  (In other words, try a pull/merge/commit, then push).

Comment: did all that, there are no new changes. What I noticed is that when I try to do forced push in UI on the bottom it shows you what it is doing. It says "Bundling x out of 914" files, when it gets to "758 out of 914 files" it freezes for about a minute and then I get invalid argument error. There must be some file that is corrupt or too big...

Comment: What version of Mercurial are you using (hg version)?  Can you try hg push --debug --verbose --time --traceback on the command line, and copy/paste the results?  Another thing to try would be smaller push increments, with hg push -r [revision #]

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't have much time so I just deleted my local copy and got it from BitBucket, but I will keep in mind your suggestion if it happens again.